# PHP: Get Last Data from Function

Tags: php

I have this code that get me last status on facebook:-

```
<?php 
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
# Gets the data from a URL
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
  $data = get_data("[url]");
  $result = json_decode($data);

  $latest_post =  $result->data[0];
  $latest_post_text = $latest_post->message;
  $latest_post_link = $latest_post->actions[0]->link;

?>
```

When I print like this :-

```
<a href="<?php echo $latest_post_link ?>"><?php echo $latest_post_text ?></a>
```

Its Show me only last status. i need to get me last 3 status. how can i do that ??

Answer (score 1):

you will need loop to show data

```
<?php 
  $counter = 0; // Add a counter to your code
  foreach ($result->data as $latest):
  $counter++; //Icrement your counter
  if ($counter > 3) { break; } // Stop foreach after 3 loops
?> 

<a href="<?php echo $latest->actions[0]->link; ?>"><?php echo $latest->message; ?></a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Nice but it get me all status, How can get only 3 from this loop

Comment: I added a break after tree occurrences in this example, so now it should only return 3